# Unix SVN Client Password Encryption

Tags: svn, gnupg

My company is looking at SVN for our new version control tool but are worried that it stores passwords in plain text for our Unix users.

I saw that SVN now offers an alternative for GNOME and KDE users where the password is stored in a keyring, but many of our Unix users don't use either desktop environment.

I'm looking for any alternative out there that can encrypt the passwords.  I did find a [dissertation from 2010](http://www.stylesen.org/files/senthil-bits-dissertation.pdf) that described using the GNU Privacy Guard's GPG-Agent to act as a keyring for *nix OS's that didn't already have a keyring.  The solution looks great, but I can't find any examples for how to install it.  Does anyone know what happened to this project?  The author was working in conjunction with Collab.Net and seemed to have a working demo put together.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Clarification**

I'm referring to the SVN client.  It cache's passwords for user's convenience so they don't need to retype their credentials for every operation.  In Windows it encrypts that stored password.  In Mac, GNOME and KDE it uses a keyring to encrypt and store them.  In all other *nix Desktop environments it stores them as plain text.  As we don't use GNOME or KDE this makes management very uncomfortable. See [SVN Client Password Caching](http://www.linuxforu.com/2009/05/subversion-16-security-improvements-illustrated/)

Comment: Only *one* of the Subversion server options (svnserve) stores passwords in plaintext by default. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html for other options.

Comment: Hey @Greg Hewgill, I meant the SVN client stores passwords as plain text by default for Unix users.  SVN clients cache passwords for convenience, but the Unix SVN client stores that password in plain text: http://www.linuxforu.com/2009/05/subversion-16-security-improvements-illustrated/

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I would use SSH with a key agent, no password storage going on there.

Comment: Thanks, that may make sense, but management would really like LDAP authentication.  I'll wait and see if anyone has worked with this problem before

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/subversion/EncryptedPasswordStorage says that "1.8-dev codebase currently offers an integration with GPG Agent"